# Microarray t-test in for control and treated group

Tags: t-test, p-value, biostatistics, microarray

I am confused with applying student's t-test with my biological experiment (even after checking you-tube videos and blogs). I have microarray data from control and hormone-treated plants with 2 replicates each and looks like this,

```
ctrl-rep1   ctrl-rep2   treated-rep1  treated-rep2
6.11        6.44        7.26          7.08
8.46        9.07        8.99          8.81
12.74       13.98       12.22         13.13
7.22        6.12        7.08          6.51
15.5        16.48       16.67         16.89
```

Since gene expression can be induced OR reduced upon hormone treatment, I assume **two-tail t-test** is fit in this case. However, I am not sure about the **type** of the test to be applied. I assume **it is unpaired** t-test based on a discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274439/paired-t-test-or-an-unpaired-t-test). If I decide to use, unpaired t-test, how can I determine it is unpaired with equal variance or unpaired with unequal variance?

Comment: If this is a standard microarray analysis involving thousands of genes at a time, you also have to take into account your multiple statistical comparisons. For example, at _p_ < 0.05 for each individual test you will come up with about 500 false-positive results if you test 10,000 genes. The `limma` package, noted in the helpful answer from @SmallChess, not only takes that into account but also uses estimates of variance based on results from all the genes to provide more power than a set of repeated _t_-tests. Use software designed for microarray analysis, like `limma`.

Answer (score 1):

A nice background reading on microarray t-test is the `limma` Bioconductor package. It's a very popular package for what you're doing, and I personally take it like a bible. Give it a read when you have an opportunity.

**1. Paired vs independent**

Let's take a look what a typical paired samples should be:

> https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf
>
> Paired samples occur when we compare two treatments and each sample given one treatment is
>   naturally paired with a particular sample given the other treatment. This is a special case of blocking
>   with blocks of size two. The classical test associated with this situation is the paired t-test. Suppose an experiment is conducted to compare a new treatment (T) with a control (C). Six dogs are used from three sib-ships. For each sib-pair, one dog is given the treatment while the other
>   dog is a control.

What it really mean is that, if you apply both control and treatment to the same biology source, it's a repeated measurement and therefore you should use the paired t-test.

There is no information on how you conducted your experiment in your question, so I assume your samples are independent and therefore you should use the independent t-test. But please double check.

**2. Equal or unequal variance**

This is normally not a problem in my works because I just run the `limma` package and let it figure out the variance... (it uses a Bayesian denominator, but let's not get into that).

There's no right or wrong answer on how you assume your variance. From what I see your data, the variance looks quite close in your control samples and treatment samples. You might want make box-plots for your samples and decide if the equal variance assumption is reasonable. There're some formal ways to do that, but a simple box-plot visualization should be sufficient.